# Spring Boot Samples FileNot found error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am folowing the examples about spring boot project. 
I have compiled and created a jar file via maven but having an error while running attempt.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple

Project folders:
[image]

**Error:**

java -jar spring-boot-sample-simple-1.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

```
014-06-25 09:10:00.653 ERROR 12028 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load configuration files
       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:158)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.j
va:138)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.j
va:131)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:120)
       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:59)
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:277)
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:944)
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:933)
       at sample.simple.SampleSimpleApplication.main(SampleSimpleApplication.java:46)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
aused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
       at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:132)
       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:121)
       at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.load(PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.java:44)
       at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader.load(PropertySourcesLoader.java:126)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:360)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:349)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:317)
       at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:155)
       ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `application.properties` should be in the `src\main\resources` folder

Answer (score 1):

There's a [bug in Spring Boot 1.1.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1145) that causes some problems with class loading on Windows when you try to run your app from a jar file. I'd recommend dropping back to 1.1.1 until it's fixed.

Comment: [Spring Boot 1.1.3](https://spring.io/blog/2014/06/27/spring-boot-1-1-3-available-now) has been released to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `application.properties` file. With Spring Boot you can place this file at the same level as the jar file and it will use that file. Have a look at the docs for more info [link here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: But spring is searching properties file at classpath as springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172). And application.properties file is located at jar file means that it is in classpath/