# Creating a custom Jasypt PropertySource in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

I'm using Spring Boot to create a simple web application which accesses a database. I'm taking advantage of the autoconfiguration functionality for the DataSource by setting up `spring.datasource.*` properties in `application.properties`. That all works brilliantly and was very quick - great work guys @ Spring!

My companys policy is that there should be no clear text passwords. Therefore I need to have the `sping.datasource.password` encrypted. After a bit of digging around I decided to create a `org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader` implementation which creates a jasypt `org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertiesPropertySource` as follows:

```
public class EncryptedPropertySourceLoader implements PropertySourceLoader
{
    private final StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();

    public EncryptedPropertySourceLoader()
    {
        //TODO: this could be taken from an environment variable
        this.encryptor.setPassword("password"); 
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getFileExtensions()
    {
        return new String[]{"properties"};
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> load(final String name, final Resource resource, final String profile) throws IOException
    {
        if (profile == null)
        {
            final Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

            if (!props.isEmpty())
            {
                return new EncryptablePropertiesPropertySource(name, props, this.encryptor);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I then packaged this in it's own jar with a `META-INF/spring.factories` file as follows:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=com.mycompany.spring.boot.env.EncryptedPropertySourceLoader
```

This works perfectly when run from maven using `mvn spring-boot:run`. The problem occurs when I run it as a standalone war using `java -jar my-app.war`. The application still loads but fails when I try to connect to the database as the password value is still encrypted. Adding logging reveals that the `EncryptedPropertySourceLoader` is never loaded.

To me this sounds like a classpath issue. When run under maven the jar loading order is strict but once under the embebed tomcat there is nothing to say that my custom jar should be loaded before Spring Boot.

I've tried adding the following to my pom.xml to ensure the classpth is preserved but it doesn't seem to have had any effect.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

A step forward: I've managed to fix this by having the `EncryptedPropertySourceLoader` class implement `org.springframework.core.PriorityOrdered` interface and returning `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` from `getOrder()`. This has now fixed the issue of the PropertySourceLoader not being used. However it's now throwing the following error when it tries to decrypt the properties:

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:716)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:553)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:705)
    at org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.java:72)
    at org.jasypt.properties.EncryptableProperties.decode(EncryptableProperties.java:230)
    at org.jasypt.properties.EncryptableProperties.get(EncryptableProperties.java:209)
    at org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource.getProperty(MapPropertySource.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnumerableCompositePropertySource.getProperty(EnumerableCompositePropertySource.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$ConfigurationPropertySources.getProperty(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:490)
```

Again this doesn't happen when running from `mvn spring-boot:run` but does happen when running from the executable war file. Both scenarios use the same JVM (jdk1.6.0_35). Results on Google/Stackoverflow suggest this is an issue with the java security policy but as it does work when run from maven I think I can discount that. Possibly a packaging issue...

Comment: The `spring.factories` are in a jar in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Yep. Opening the WAR generated from maven gives `my-app.war!WEB-INF/lib/utility.jar!META-INF/spring.factories`

Comment: I guess it's a classloader issue then. Does it work in a JAR (as opposed to a WAR)?

Comment: See update: It now uses the custom PropertySourceLoader (as it now implement PriorityOrdered) but still facing some issue which I susspect are related to the difference maven vs executable jar.

Comment: Does it work in a JAR?

Comment: No. But I may be having more fundamental issues as I'm getting the same error when I try to run from JAR with or without my custom PropertySourceLoader. I've even tried one of the sample projects and I get the same error which is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist` thrown from `PropertyLoaderUtils`

I will investigate this further and try to get a working sample JAR with application.properties working first.

Comment: Just to clarify: spring.factories works just fine in a nested jar (or war): proof being that spring-boot-autoconfigure has that feature and it always works. So if you are having issues they might be more to do with Jasypt. I'll give it a try if you can send a link to a minimal project.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I spotted the answer in another post [24415926](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410532/spring-boot-samples-filenot-found-error/24415926#24415926) which states that there is a problem in spring-boot 1.1.2.RELEASE. I dropped back to v1.1.1.RELEASE and both my problems went away. So yes to clarify. The above code does work in JAR and WAR (as long as it's modified to use PriorityOrded) just not in v1.1.2.RELEASE

Comment: Ah, Windows user? Did you notice that 1.1.3 is out?

Comment: Yes, this is being developed/tested on Windows7. I've also tested successfully with 1.1.3. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1) The EncryptedPropertySourceLoader needs to be loaded higher than then standard PropertiesPropertySourceLoader. This can be achieved by implementing the PriorityOrder interface as follows:

```
public class EncryptedPropertySourceLoader implements PropertySourceLoader, PriorityOrdered
{
    private final StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();

    public EncryptedPropertySourceLoader()
    {
        this.encryptor.setPassword("password"); //TODO: this could be taken from an environment variable
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getFileExtensions()
    {
        return new String[]{"properties"};
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> load(final String name, final Resource resource, final String profile) throws IOException
    {
        if (profile == null)
        {
            //load the properties
            final Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

            if (!props.isEmpty())
            {
                //create the encryptable properties property source
                return new EncryptablePropertiesPropertySource(name, props, this.encryptor);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder()
    {
        return HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

The `org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader` class which loads the `org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader` from the `META-INF/spring.factories` orders the results using `org.springframework.core.OrderComparator`. Meaning that this class should be returned first and will be given the responsibility of providinging the PropertySourceLoader implementation for *.proerpties files.

2) The second is a class loading issue with the executable JAR/WAR which seems to be caused by a bug in version 1.1.2.RELEASE of Spring Boot on Windows. Dropping to version 1.1.1.RELEASE or to version 1.1.3.RELEASE solves the various issues with classes and proerpties file not being loaded when run outside of maven.

Comment: I am using exactly same code and spring.factoryies file with version 1.2.3.RELEASE but it is not loading my EncryptedPropertySourceLoader. For an indication of load I am throwing a RuntimeException from load method but it seems this method is not being called. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Here is the link to complete question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31824601/spring-boot-not-loading-propertysourceloader

Answer (score 6):

You could give this a try: [jasypt-spring-boot](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot)
It basically wraps all PropertySource present in the Environment with an encryptable version. The 2 things you gotta do once you import the library (adding the dependency if you use maven) is to annotate your @Configuration class with @EnableEncryptableProperties, and to configure the encryption algorithm and password through properties.

Comment: Hi Ulises, is this library jasypt outdated ? 
its not been updating since 2014 March. 

Is it safe to use it in the project ?

Comment: I've used it for a couple of years now to encrypt sensitive properties. The library is just a wrapper of the JDK provided algorithms. It just makes them easier to use.