# Spring boot not loading PropertySourceLoader

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

With spring boot version 1.2.3 (also tested it with 1.2.5), I am following [creating-a-custom-jasypt-propertysource-in-springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451110/creating-a-custom-jasypt-propertysource-in-springboot) and [Spring Boot & Jasypt easy: Keep your sensitive properties encrypted](http://www.seropian.eu/2015_05_01_archive.html) to use jsypt library using custom PropertySourceLoader. My source loader class is in api.jar and this jar file is included in myapplication.war file. This war is deployed in tomcat.

It seems that spring is not loading `EncryptedPropertySourceLoader` on application startup. Can anyone please help?

Following is my project structure and related code.

```
Project - api.jar
    | src
    | | main
    |   | java
    |     | EncryptedPropertySourceLoader.java
    |   | resources
    |     | META-INF
    |       | spring.factories
```

The api.jar is build with `api.jar!META-INF/spring.factories`.

```
package com.test.boot.env;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.PriorityOrdered;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class EncryptedPropertySourceLoader implements PropertySourceLoader, PriorityOrdered {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptedPropertySourceLoader.class);


    public EncryptedPropertySourceLoader() {
        logger.error("\n\n\n***CREATING properties loader.\n\n\n");
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getFileExtensions() {
        return new String[] { "properties" };
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> load(final String name, final Resource resource, final String profile) throws IOException {
        logger.error("\n\n\n***Loading properties files.\n\n\n");

        if (true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("calling load"); \\intentional to identify the call
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

The spring.factories contents are

```
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=\
com.test.boot.env.EncryptedPropertySourceLoader
```

I have also tried without '\' but it does not make any difference.

Following is the path of `spring.factories` in `myapplication.war` file

```
myapplication.war!WEB-INF/lib/api.jar!META-INF/spring.factories
```

As per my understanding, I should see the `RuntimeException` on startup but my application is starting successfully. Can anyone please help to find what I am be missing?

Comment: You can use this library: [jasypt-spring-boot][1] for which the only thing you'll have to do is to add a maven dependency (jasypt-spring-boot-starter) and provide the decryption key through a System Property when you run the app.


  [1]: https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot

Comment: thanks @Ulises can you plz guide me what error do I have in my setup as mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

For what I can tell the `SpringFactoriesLoader` mechanism for factory `PropertySourceLoader` is only used by `PropertySourcesLoader` which in turn is ONLY used to load the application properties. Those are either `application.properties`, `application.yml`, or `application.yaml`. So for your example just add a file `application.properties` to your classpath and you'll get the exception you are expecting.
What I don't know is why other property source import mechanisms such as using annotation @PropertySource are not going through `PropertySourcesLoader` to take advantage of the factories loaders and override mechanism.

Comment: I already have application.properties in class path and they war being loaded properly